# Android project in release mode, compiles in debug

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, apk, release

I have a Android project totally rebuild from older version xamarin studio to visual studio 2015.
If I compile the project in Release mode and upload it to google play , google tells me its still in debug mode and refuses to accept.
Whatever I have tried I cant seems to get it in release mode, however the .apk appears in release folder under bin.

I have no idea anymore where to look or what to do, somebody has a bright idea what I might do wrong?

Comment: Not sure if there's anything helpful here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/578/apk-signed-in-debug-mode

Comment: Oh well, yes, seems the release output is in the main directory.... answer was in some guy is update...EDIT: Turns out the OUTPUT of the PUBLISH is NOT the same location as export nor normal build - it outputs the apk in the root of the android-project dir. Un-expected. Didn't see that until doing a code checkin to repo and observing a 'new file' in changeset the list.

Hopefully that helps someone else...